# Capturing video from a MJPEG stream using C++

Tags: c++, c, opencv, ffmpeg, mjpeg

I would like to capture a MJPEG stream using C++. Which options do I have? I have tried OpenCV with FFMPEG support but icvCreateFileCapture_FFMPEG_p is always returning null (after a few seconds of timeout). May I program a HTTP client by myself?

Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

M-JPEG is easy to capture. You send one HTTP request to the server and read back infinite response in `multipart/x-mixed-replace` format (Content-Type). Then you split it into frames, which are self-contained JPEG files... Subheaders might or moight not contain additional information such as timestamps.

You might find this relevant and useful as well: [How to parse MJPEG HTTP Stream within C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801933/how-to-parse-mjpeg-http-stream-within-c)